# How to inject non-default entity managers?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

In Symfony2 you can work with multiple entity managers and use something like the code below:

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('default');

$customerEm =  $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('customer');
```

We can inject the default manager to any service by using:

```
"@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

How can you inject non-default entity managers into services?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If your entity managers config name is `non_default` then you can reference it as `@doctrine.orm.non_default_entity_manager`

Comment: Just to make sure, it is required to create it as a service right.

Comment: No need to create service. Symfony will automatically create it. Same also holds for connections.

Comment: Also you can issue `php app/console container:debug` command to verify it.

Comment: Yes, it's working and it's better solution than mine - so if it's possible with stackoverflow to change accepted answer this one should be accepted. Best!

Comment: The other solutions works too but this is better unless for some reason we need define the service manually.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are using Symfony 3+, use the console :
`php bin/console debug:container`

Then you should see many lines starting with : 'doctrine.orm.MY_CUSTOM_ENTITY_MANAGER_xxxxxxxxxx'

So if you want the entity manager corresponding to your custom entity manager, find the line :
'doctrine.orm.MY_CUSTOM_ENTITY_MANAGER_entity_manager'

You can insert it in your service arguments.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You should define your custom entity manager as a service:

```
services:  
    name_of_your_custom_manager:
        class: %doctrine.orm.entity_manager.class%
        factory_service:  doctrine
        factory_method:   getEntityManager
        arguments: ["name_of_your_custom_manager"]
```

Then, you can inject it in the same way as you do with every service:

```
@name_of_your_custom_manager
```

**Edit**:

Pay attention that factory method may differ between symfony's version (it could be `getEntityManager` or `getManager`)

Answer (score 1):

Hello first of all create your manager, in my example I create the manager for my Item class that is in a CoreBundle:

```
<?php
// src/Sybio/Bundle/CoreBundle/Manager/ItemManager.php:

namespace Sybio\Bundle\CoreBundle\Manager;

use Sybio\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Item;

class ItemManager
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em entity manager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $em repository
     */
    protected $repository;

    /**
     * @var string $entityName
     */
    protected $entityName;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @param string $entityName
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $entityName)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->repository = $em->getRepository($entityName);
        $this->entityName = $entityName;
    }

    /**
     * Save a entity object
     *
     * @param Object $entity
     * 
     * @return Object Entity
     */
    public function save($entity)
    {
        $this->persistAndFlush($entity);

        return $entity;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a entity object
     *
     * @param Object $entity
     * 
     * @return Object Entity
     */
    public function remove($entity)
    {
        return $this->removeAndFlush($entity);
    }

    /**
     * Persist object
     *
     * @param mixed $entity
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    protected function persistAndFlush($entity)
    {
        $this->em->persist($entity);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    /**
     * Remove object
     *
     * @param mixed $entity entity to remove
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    protected function removeAndFlush($entity)
    {
        $this->em->remove($entity);
        $this->em->flush();
    }

    /**
     * Returns entity repository object
     * 
     * @return EntityRepository
     */
    public function getRepository()
    {
        return $this->repository;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new object
     * 
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createNewObject()
    {
        return new Item();
    }

    // Create your own methods to manage the object

}
```

If the manager structure is shared between multiple manager, you can create a BaseManager extended by all other managers !

Then register it in the services.yml (or xml) file of your bundle:

```
# src/Sybio/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/services.yml or xml !:

parameters:

    # Managers _________________

    sybio.item_manager.entity: SybioCoreBundle:Item
    sybio.item_manager.class: Sybio\Bundle\CoreBundle\Manager\ItemManager

services:

    # Managers _________________

    sybio.item_manager:
        class:        %sybio.item_manager.class%
        arguments:    [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, %sybio.item_manager.entity%]
```

That's it, you can now use it:

```
// Controller:

$im =  $this->get('sybio.item_manager');

$item = $im->createNewObject();
$im->save($item);
```

You can then improve your manager, here I give an array of config parameters to my manager:

```
# src/Sybio/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/services.yml or xml !:

sybio.item_manager:
        class:        %sybio.item_manager.class%
        arguments:    [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, %sybio.item_manager.entity%, {'item_removed_state': %item_removed_state%, 'item_unpublished_state': %item_unpublished_state%, 'item_published_state': %item_published_state%}]


// src/Sybio/Bundle/CoreBundle/Manager/ItemManager.php:

public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $entityName, $params = array()) {
    // ...
    $this->params = $params;
}
```

If you create a BaseManager, you can also create a usefull generic method to initialize an object:

```
// src/Sybio/Bundle/CoreBundle/Manager/BaseManager.php:

/**
 * Create a new object
 * 
 * @return mixed
 */
public function createNewObject()
{
    $entityName = explode(":", $this->entityName);
    $entityName = "Sybio\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\\".$entityName[1];

    return new $entityName;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you injecting the default entity manager with '@doctrine.orm.entity_manage'?