# symfony2 - using multiple connections in a repository or class

Tags: php, symfony, database-connection, multiple-databases

I have multiple connections and I have a repository class.  I would like the repository class to have access to the multiple connections.  Its for a report that requires fetching data from multiple database hosts.

**config.yml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:  default
        connections:
          default:
              driver:   "%db_default_driver%"
              host:     "%db_default_host%"
              etc..
          bookings:
              driver:   "%db_readonly_bookings_driver%"
              host:     "%db_readonly_bookings_host%"
              etc ...
          sessions:
              etc..
```

**SalesJournalRepistory.php**

```
namespace Portal\SalesJournalBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class SalesJournalRepository extends EntityRepository 
{

  public $connDefault   = null;
  public $connBookings  = null;
  public $connSessions  = null;


  function __construct()
  {
    // this is where I get the error
    $this->connDefault  = $this->getManager('default')->getConnection();
    $this->connBookings = $this->getManager('bookings')->getConnection();
    $this->connSessions = $this->getManager('sessions')->getConnection();
  }

  function testQuery(){
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM testTableBookings LIMIT 10";
     $stmt = $this->connBookings->prepare($sql);
     $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

     print_r($results);
  }

  function testQuery2(){
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM testTableSessions LIMIT 10";
     $stmt = $this->connSessions->prepare($sql);
     $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

     print_r($results);
  }


}
```

I can make it work from the a controller

```
$connDefault  = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default')->getConnection();
$connBookings = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('bookings')->getConnection();
```

however im looking to be able to run it from the repository.  Im getting the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getConnection() on a non-object
```

I thought this may give some clue? [enjecting entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118288/how-to-inject-non-default-entity-managers) however I am a little confused and not sure if it is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An `EntityRepository` should only be concerned with its owning entity (and manager)- so mixing your Entity Repositories with your Entity Managers really isn't the way to go. I suggest you create yourself a service and inject Doctrine - then you can query whatever you want. For example :

the config

```
[config.yml / services.yml]
services:
   sales_journal:
      class: Acme\DemoBundle\Service\SalesJournal
       arguments: ['@doctrine']
```

the service

```
[Acme\DemoBundle\Service\SalesJournal.php]

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Service;

public class SalesJournal {

    private $connDefault;
    private $connBookings;
    private $connSessions;


    function __construct($doctrine)
    {
        $this->connDefault = $doctrine->getManager('default')->getConnection();
        $this->connBookings = $doctrine->getManager('bookings')->getConnection();
        $this->connSessions = $doctrine->getManager('sessions')->getConnection();
    }

    function testQuery()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM testTableBookings LIMIT 10";
        $stmt = $this->connBookings->prepare($sql);
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

        print_r($results);
    }

    function testQuery2()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM testTableSessions LIMIT 10";
        $stmt = $this->connSessions->prepare($sql);
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

        print_r($results);
    }
}
```

then from your controller or where ever you want to use the service you can do :

```
// get the service
$sales_journal = $this->get('sales_journal');
// call relevent function
$sales_journal->testQuery();
```

Comment: yay it worked - thanks.  I have been stuck on this for quite some time.  I kept it in the repository folder but didnt use the extend EntityRepository.  I'm not sure its a service as its just a report and im told that queries belong in the Repository folder.  What do you think of that setup?

Comment: @Robbo_UK you can put your services anywhere - but i would suggest that the repositories folder is for repositories ... Its OK to create new folders

Answer (score 2):

you should set entity manager you want to use in controller as second parameter of getRepository method like this:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PortalSalesJournalBundle:SalesJournal', 'bookings');
```

and access that entity manager's connection in repository class like this:

```
namespace Portal\SalesJournalBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class SalesJournalRepository extends EntityRepository 
{
    function testQuery(){
        $connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but im looking to use all of the connections?  The above example seems only specific to one connection?