# Symfony multiple sites one application

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Let's say I'm making a multi-company application and thus root of every entity starts with domain which is known by subdomain/currently logged user.

Is there a way to force `Doctrine` to limit every query to specific `company_id`? I'm also interested on a solution with forms to do that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're on the wrong track here... consider giving each *company* their own database and register multiple entity-managers - one for each company ... then you only need to switch between entity-managers on a per-request basis. Or do you want to create *company_id* entries for every entry in every table ?! That's gonna end up in a huge mess. Distinct databases will be easier to maintain, backup ... Or am i getting something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I can give you a few ideas:

Options for Queries (Doctrine). I suppose that you have a "company_id" column in all your database tables => a company attribute in all you entities.

1) Create query global filters. Take a look at : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html

2) Create an abstract base repository where you could do sth like:

```
abstract class BaseRepository {
    //...
    protected function getQBDefault($company) {
        $alias = $this->getClassAlias();
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder($alias)
            ->where($alias . '.company = :company')
            ->setParameter('company', $company);

        return $query;
    }

    abstract function getClassAlias();
}

class MyRepository extends BaseRepository {
//....
    public function findMyResults($company) {
        $qb = $this->getQBDefault($company);
        //DO STH WITH THIS QUERY BUILDER
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

3) Extend Doctrine EntityManager to apply your filter by company to every query. So you use your own-custom-service instead of the default one wherever you want.

References:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

[How to inject non-default entity managers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118288/how-to-inject-non-default-entity-managers)

For the forms: could you tell me what you want to do?

If you are more specific, I can help you better ;).